# make button wait for user input before continuing

Tags: vb.net, button, textbox, wait

I’ve gotten into a spot of trouble and cant figure my way out

I’m trying to click a button and then get the user to type an input in textboxs, 7 and 8, then reuse the textboxes 7 and 8 to get the next two values, and once that is all done that the line is drawn…

```
    Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim myPen As New System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red)
    Dim formGraphics As System.Drawing.Graphics

    Dim x1 As Integer
    Dim y1 As Integer
    Dim x2 As Integer
    Dim y2 As Integer

    x1 = TextBox7.Text
    y1 = TextBox8.Text

    'clears textbox values...
    TextBox7.Text = ""
    TextBox8.Text = ""

    'set focus to textbox7...
    TextBox7.Focus()

    x2 = TextBox7.Text
    y2 = TextBox8.Text

    formGraphics = Me.CreateGraphics()
    formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, x1, y1, x2, y2)
    myPen.Dispose()
    formGraphics.Dispose()
End Sub
```

At current the textbox's need to be filled first before the button is clicked, I want it the otherway around..

Dose anybody know how to do this?

ussing VB.net...

Answer (score 0):

do you want to handle the textbox textchanged event so that whenever the text in the textboxes is changed you check if it completes your criteria?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.textchanged.aspx

You'll also need to break your code up into several different subroutines